# How to run ruby script as a task from ant build?

Tags: ant

I have an exiting ant build that is called via `ant -lib lib -f test_build.xml`

I wanted to add one more `<target>` section to be run after the existing one finishes. I did some research and found [ant manual for exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) and even [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534973/how-can-i-run-perl-and-ruby-scripts-as-tasks-in-ant) here on SO. After some reading I added new target to this existing build but it didn't work.

I tried to create new build file only with my target. It doesn't work either. Although the ant run finishes with message `BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds`

If I run my ruby script from a command line it works. I tried to create bat file that would call my ruby script with the same result. If I call the bat file from dos window it works.

My ant run build file looks like

```
<project name="RunRubyExample">

<target name="calling ruby " >
  <exec executable="ruby.exe">
    <arg value="C:\EduTester\others\afterant.rb 1 2 tri four"/>
  </exec>
</target>

<target name="calling batach">
  <exec executable="cmd">
    <arg value="/c"/>
    <arg value="C:\EduTester\others\rubruby.bat 1 2 tri four"/>
  </exec>
</target>

</project>
```

- Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
- on Windows XP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're passing a single arg **value** with embedded spaces

```
<arg value="C:\EduTester\others\afterant.rb 1 2 tri four"/>
```

Is that right?  Or should it be either an arg **line**:

```
<arg line="C:\EduTester\others\afterant.rb 1 2 tri four"/>
```

or multiple arg values:

```
<arg value="C:\EduTester\others\afterant.rb"/>
<arg value="1"/>
<arg value="2"/>
<arg value="tri"/>
<arg value="four"/>
```

Comment: I tried both `line` and separate the line with spaces into multiple argument lines. None worked. I only get `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`. Is there any way to debug ant run?

Comment: "Radek - you could try `ant -debug` followed by your other args.  You could also look at the failonerror, errorproperty, outputproperty attributes of the [`exec` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) - might be able to capture more info in those.

Comment: debug and failonerror didn't provide any new info. I don't know how to use the other ones `errorproperty, outputproperty`. Is there any way how to find out if ant run what was specified in exec?

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be specified target that needs to be run

- either by `<project name="RunRubyExample" default="callingruby">`
- or when calling the ant build file. Where we pass the target name we want to be run as an argument. `ant -lib lib callingruby`

[Writing a Simple Buildfile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html)

Thank you @Steve