# How to run a ruby file from ant script?

Tags: ant

I need to run a ruby file(EG: d:\ruby\ruby file.rb) in command prompt by calling the file from ant script. I need the ant script. Can anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I run perl and ruby scripts as tasks in ant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534973/how-can-i-run-perl-and-ruby-scripts-as-tasks-in-ant)

Answer (score 2):

You would probably just use `<exec>` on ruby with the rb file as the first argument.

Something like this:

```
<exec executable="c:\Ruby192\bin\ruby.exe" dir="d:\ruby">
    <arg value="d:\ruby\ruby file.rb"/>
</exec>
```

It depends on where ruby.exe is installed, and if it's in your PATH.

Comment: can you send me the full script?

Comment: While executing the script got the following error                 [exec] D:/Ruby/Ruby 1.8.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:27:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- ./data (LoadError)
[exec]     from D:/Ruby/Ruby 1.8.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:27:in `require'
[exec]     from D:/eclipse-indigo-projects/Agora/launchapp.rb:6
[exec] Result: 1                                                         what is the issue?

Comment: Seems like a ruby problem at this point, have you successfully gotten the ruby script to run outside of ant?